# Is there a build of google-api-dotnet-client that is compatible with .Net Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, .net-4.8

My project w/c uses google-api-dotnet-client need to be upgrade from .Net Framework 4.5 to 4.8 in order to utilize TLS1.3. Is there a version of google-api-dotnet-client that is compatible w/ .Net Framework 4.8?

Comment: Most 4.5-targeted libraries are already “(forward) compatible” with the 4.8-runtime. There are a few very *rare* wrinkles here and there although many package authors are happy leaving it at an older version if not wanting to use features provided in a newer targeting version. So: is the current library *actually incompatible* with the .Net 4.8 application?

Comment: (Because if it’s not actually incompatible; don’t worry about it. Also, asking for a library, or even an update of such, is Off Topic without a very specific question relating to some actual well-defined issue.)

Comment: @user2864740 It looks like it or maybe something was missed during the upgrade, but when I run my app, I get a `FileNotFoundException`: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70782146/168345#comment125134175_70782146
Managed to solve this by updating the `targetFramework` attributes in packages.config from `net40` to `net48`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google api .net client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client) supports 4.5+ so yes it supports .net framework 4.8 just keep an eye on the EOL for that version of .net framework at some point support for EOL versions is removed.

[image]

Even if it does not longer support it you should be able to use an outdate package on Nuget those packages should still work unless there is some major change within the api you are using, which doesnt happen often.